# Why is the plural verb 'are' used in 'among the most eye-catching pieces in the whole collection are'?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, grammatical-number

> For example, among the most eye-catching pieces in the whole collection **are** the marble animal sculptures under two arches on the left of the entrance hall.

I think 'among the most eye-catching pieces in the whole collection' is a clause, so the following verb needs to be a singular verb, why is there a plural verb 'are' here? Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Among the most eye-catching pieces [...]" is a prepositional phrase. It doesn't behave as a noun; instead, it modifies the plural subject, "the marble animal sculpture**s** [...]", as if it were an adjective.

This sentence doesn't follow the subject-first syntax typical of English. The expected order would be

> The marble animal sculptures under two arches on the left of the entrance hall **are** among the most eye-catching pieces in the whole collection.

having the structure of subject + copula + subject complement. However, it's possible to put the complement first, especially

1. in archaic or poetic writing, often because it facilitates rhyming, and
2. when inverting the order makes a wordy sentence easier to follow by clarifying its structure or its important information early on.

In this case, both the subject and its complement are wordy, but the complement's significance follows from the context before it, while the subject's significance relies on the complement. Why should you care where the marble animal sculptures are located before you understand how they're related to what you were reading a second ago?

It appears there's [a whole Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions) on this, if you're interested.

Answer (score 6):

The "are" applies to "the marble animal sculptures", not "eye-catching pieces in the whole collection". If the singled-out item were singular then the verb should indeed be singular. But in this case the focus is on more than one statue.